# Ruby How to convert string to integer without .to_i

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to output an integer given a string containing numbers between 0 and 9. For example, input is "219", output would be 219, and you can't use .to_i

Comment: Why can't you use `to_i`?

Comment: @muistooshort it's a whiteboarding question and that is the challenge.

Comment: If you let someone else do the work, it's not a challenge.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Well if you'd take the time to scroll down a bit instead of just being snarky, you'll see MY solution. I wanted to see other solutions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Kernel::Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer):

```
Integer("219")
  #=> 219 
Integer("21cat9")
  # ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "21cat9"
```

Sometimes this method is used as follows:

```
def convert_to_i(str)
  begin
    Integer(str)
  rescue ArgumentError
    nil
  end
end

convert_to_i("219")
  #=> 219
convert_to_i("21cat9")
  #=> nil
convert_to_i("1_234")
  #=> 1234
convert_to_i("  12  ")
  #=> 12 
convert_to_i("0b11011") # binary representation
  #=> 27 
convert_to_i("054")     # octal representation
  #=> 44
convert_to_i("0xC")     # hexidecimal representation
  #=> 12
```

Some use an "inline rescue" (though it is less selective, as it rescues all exceptions):

```
def convert_to_i(str)
  Integer(str) rescue nil
end
```

There are similar Kernel methods to convert a string to a float or rational.

Comment: Integer("0054")
 => 44

Comment: @morrime that would be `Integer("0054", 10)`. Read the docs that @Cary linked to

Comment: It works with "007", but not with "008". That's because octal 7 (07) is the same as decimal 7 and `Integer("008") #=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "008"`. @luka, good point.

Answer (score 2):

```
def str_to_int(string)
 digit_hash = {"0" => 0, "1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" => 3, "4" => 4, "5" => 5, "6" => 6, "7" => 7, "8" => 8, "9" => 9}
 total = 0
 num_array = string.split("").reverse
 num_array.length.times do |i|
   num_value = digit_hash[num_array[i]]
   num_value_base_ten = num_value * (10**i)
   total += num_value_base_ten
 end
 return total
end

puts str_to_int("119") # => 119
```

Comment: Don't forget negative integers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I should have mentioned it earlier, but the parameters of the whiteboarding problem say the string is ONLY characters from 0-9, so negatives aren't possible.

Comment: An alternative to the hash is `num_array[i].ord - 48`.  Consider using [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) and [Array#reverse_each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each): `str = "123"; fac = 1; str.chars.reverse_each.reduce(0) do |tot, digit|; tot += (digit.ord - 48)*fac; fac *= 10; tot; end`.